# Is there a way to remove all characters within two slashes?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use only regex to remove '/please-remove-this/' and replace '%20' with ' '.

```
let str = '/please-remove-this/Hello%20world'

let strNew = str.replace(/%20/g, ' ').substring(20)

strNew = 'Hello world'
```

'Hello world' is the correct output but I feel there is a more efficient way to do this with regex only

Comment: `str = str.replace(/\/[^\/]*\//g, '').replace('%20', ' ')`

Comment: If the code works for you, please consider asking for improvements at [codereview.se].

Comment: This code looks problematic not because of efficiency, but because it requires hard-coding the position of the last `/`

Comment: `indexOfSecondSlash = str.indexOf('/', 1); strNew = str.slice(indexOfSecondSlash+1);` if you wanna go without regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather replacing `%20` you can decode using `decodeURI`

```js
let str = '/please-remove-this/Hello%20world';
let out = decodeURI(str.replace(/\/.*\//g, ''));
console.log(out)
```

Using only regex

```js
let str = '/please-remove-this/Hello%20world';
let out = decodeURI(str.replace(/\/.*\/(.*)%20(.*)/, '$1 $2'));
console.log(out)
```

Comment: Great answer! I wasn't aware I could use decodeURI - thank you!